# ng-select show empty option-group text

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ngselect, ng-template

Is it possible to show a default text, if an option-group is empty?

```html
<ng-select #locationDropdown 
[items]="data" 
[disabled]="true" 
class="form-control custom" 
formControlName="testLocation"
bindLabel="name" 
groupBy="testLocations" 
placeholder="Prüfort(e)" 
[closeOnSelect]="false"
[notFoundText]="'Keine Prüforte gefunden. Bitte wählen Sie ein Datum aus'" (focus)="onFilterFocus()"
multiple="true">
<ng-template ng-optgroup-tmp let-item="item">
    {{item.name}}
</ng-template>
<ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    <div title="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

I have an array that looks like this:

```
export type Root = Root2[] 

export interface Root2 { 
  id: string 
  legacyId: number 
  name: string 
  testLocations: TestLocation[] 
} 

export interface TestLocation { 
  id: string 
  legacyId: number 
  name: string 
}
```

Everything works fine. But I want to display a text like 'No items in this option-group' if testLocations: TestLocation[] is empty.

Now the empty option-groups are shown, but they have no 'child'. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please elaborate, how can a group be shown, when there is no entry for this group?

Comment: I have an array that looks like this: 

export type Root = Root2[]

export interface Root2 {
  id: string
  legacyId: number
  name: string
  testLocations: TestLocation[]
}

export interface TestLocation {
  id: string
  legacyId: number
  name: string
}

Everything works fine. But I want to display a text like 'No items in this option-group' if testLocations: TestLocation[] is empty.